# What do Azure Cloud Service Endpoints actually configure?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

In a Cloud Service Definition file, we specify the Endpoints for our Cloud Service. I understand this is used to configure Azure's own network load-balancer and also the instance's own Windows Firewall. This only needs the port number (for the load-balancer) and/or the process executable name (for Windows Firewall, if using process-based rules instead of port-number-based rules).

But what is the significance of each `protocol="http|https|tdp|udp"` attribute value?

My confusion is because `tdp` and `udp` are both transport-layer protocols - but that's enough to configure the load-balancer and firewall (as they can selectively block non-TCP or non-UDP traffic as appropriate). But what does `protocol="http"` or `protocol="https"` do, exactly?

HTTP and HTTPS are both Application-layer protocols that run on top of TCP - so if I specify `protocol="tcp"` for a WebRole then that should work for both HTTP and HTTPS traffic, right?

But what happens if I have a Worker Role (not a Web Role) Cloud Service which has a `protocol="https"` endpoint defined? What happens if my Worker Role code creates a `Socket` that listens on that particular port? And what happens to the incoming connection?

Does the load-balancer require the incoming connection to conform to the HTTP or HTTPS protocol specification? What if it's a polyglot protocol or some other protocol that *looks* like HTTP but is actually appliction-defined (e.g. SIP)?

If I specify `https` I also have to specify the certificate name - so this must mean the load-balancer is responsible for decryping TLS communication and then forwarding cleartext to the Web Role or Worker Role socket?

What if I have a Worker Role that privately makes use of `HTTP.sys` (or IIS Hostable Web Core) or self-hosts ASP.NET Core, for example, how would that be configured as the `<Sites>` element is unavailable?

Does the use of `protocol="https"` or `protocol="http"` cause any configuration of `HTTP.sys`?

Comment: Maybe can get some useful info from the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-enable-communication-role-instances) about what protocol shoud be used for input endpoints or internal endpoints, worker roles and web roles.